# POCO C++ libraries on CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, poco-libraries

I am working with CDT (C/C++ for eclipse) on windows, and I need to start using [POCO C++ libraries](http://pocoproject.org/)

The current package distribution for POCO requires MS Visual Studio 7/8/9 for compiling the libs.

Does anyone know a solution for compiling in a CDT environment on windows? I am using MinGW for compile/build tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use POCO with MinGW - some folks already do this successfully. I would first try to get going with MinGW alone, and when this works, integrate it into Eclipse (which shouldn't be too hard.).

There are some patches and bug reports in POCO's tracker on SourceForge. Looking at them will certainly help (https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=132964).